# Definition of meromorphic funciton on complex manifold

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I'm having trouble finding a definition for a meromorphic function from the Riemann sphere to itself. Denoting the sphere $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ we have that
$$f:\hat{\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow \hat{\mathbb{C}}$$ 
is holomorphic if for any coordinates $(U_1,\phi_1)$ and $(U_2,\phi_2)$ the function
$$\phi_2\circ f\circ \phi_1^{-1}:\mathbb{C}\supset \phi_1(U_1)\rightarrow \phi_2^{-1}(U_2)\subset\mathbb{C}$$

is holomorphic. How would i define a meromorphic function?

Comment: Would this definition then imply that if $h$ is harmonic on $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ then  $h\circ f$ is harmonic? I'm failing to see why this would be the case since $\underbrace{h\circ\phi_2^{-1}}_{harmonic}\circ \underbrace{\phi_2\circ f\circ \phi_1^{-1}}_{meromorphic}$ and this would only be harmonic outside a discrete set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two complex manifolds $f:M \to N$ is analytic iff $\psi^{-1}\circ f\circ \phi$ is analytic in the usual sense for enough charts.

$f:M \to \Bbb{C}$ is meromorphic iff 
$f\circ \phi$ is meromorphic (ie. $f\circ \phi= u/v$ with $u,v$ analytic and $v\ne 0$) for enough charts $\phi$.

Moreover in dimension $1$ meromorphic on $M$ is the same as analytic $M \to \Bbb{P^1(C)}$ (in dimension $\ge 2$ it is the same as analytic away from a codimension $\ge 2$ set)

There is no meaning of meromorphic $M \to N$ because we need a field structure on $N$ to define $u/v$ in a way compatible with analyticity.

Comment: Ok so  meromorphy from $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ to itself is the same as analyticity?

Comment: $\Bbb{P^1(C)}$ is $\Bbb{C} \cup \infty$ with its chart at $\infty$ so it is not a field, there is no notion of meromorphicity to it. In contrary meromorphic $M \to \Bbb{C}^*$ makes sense because you can add multiply and divide  two $\Bbb{C}^*$ valued analytic functions

Comment: Ok that is very clear now thanks. In my book the author seems to make a difference between meromorphic and conformal maps of the Riemann sphere to itself? Would conformal here then mean holomorphic + bijective?